# Ad-Hoc Deployment Crashing on Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, hockeyapp

I'm attempting to distribute an iOS 7.1 app using HockeyApp. The app works perfectly well in XCode on development devices that are attached to the computer but the app crashes on load when running from an over-the-air install from Hockey.

Here's the crash log I'm getting. As you can see, it's something to do with XCTest which I assume should not be present in an adhoc build.

```
Dyld Error Message:
<Error>:   Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
<Error>:   Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5F261236-E8C6-4F8B-9380-34445DAA3474/MyApp.app/MyApp
Reason: image not found
Dyld Version: 353.5
```

I've made sure there are no references to XCTest in my application target, but I still receive this error. Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that XCTest was included in a rogue cocoapod. By removing this, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Reason: image not found.

This seems to be that you have not copied some image in the bundle. Check all the images in the app and see that it is copied in bundle. May be you have just referenced it from some folder from MAC machine.